# How do I write a procedure or trigger that will avoid duplication of numbers in a range?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to avoid rows inserted that contain numbers in a range that has already been allocated. To avoid the overlapping I heard I can do it via triggers or by writing a PHP application logic *but the problem is I keep getting the trigger statement wrong*. This might sound awkward but I need someone to write it out for me.

I need a MySQL trigger query or procedure that will not permit users to put in numbers in a range that already exists in a database. I am dealing with cards here and the amount of cards to be manufactured by `user1` will be inserted via create page before he/she commence. While `user2` can commence on another machine but without prior info abt where `user1` started from. So for example if `user2` attempts to choose to start anything from `1`,`2`,`3`,`4`,`5`,`6`, up to `2530` a trigger or error should occur which prevents them from duplicating the range already done by `user1`

```
id |user_id| number_from | number_to | client | cardtype  | job_number | job_quant |status
1  | smith |      1      |   2530    | queens |inspiration| j290122    | 5000      |nt done
2  | john  |   2531      |   4000    | queens |inspiration| j290122    | 5000      |nt done
4  | kenny |      1      |   1500    |seabirds|   love    | j300011    | 1500      | done
3  | wayne |   4001      |   5000    | queens |inspiration| j290122    | 5000      | done
```

My code for insert in PHP which I learnt how to write using a video tutorial:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // process the form
    $user_id = (int) $_POST["user_id"];
    $number_from = $_POST["number_from"];
    $number_to = $_POST["number_to"];
    $client = mysql_prep($_POST["client"]);
    $cardtype = $_POST["cardtype"];
    $job_number = $_POST["job_number"];
    $job_quantity = $_POST["job_quantity"];
    $status = $_POST["status"];

    $query = "INSERT INTO jobs (";
    $query .= " user_id, number_from, number_to, client, cardtype, job_number, job_quantity, status";
    $query .= ") VALUES (";
    $query .= " '{$user_id}', '{$number_from}', '{$number_to}', '{$client}', '{$card_type}', '{$job_number}', '{$job_quantity}', '{$status}'";
    $query .= ")";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    if ($result) {
        // success
        $_SESSION["message"] = "job created.";
        redirect_to("manage_job.php"); 
    } else {
        // failure  
        $_SESSION["message"] = "job creation failed.";
        redirect_to("new_job.php");
    }  
} 
?>
```

I was told to try this:

Create a procedure and call it in a `BEFORE` trigger, passing the `NEW.job_number`, `new.number_from` and `new.number_to`, then querying.

Said my code would then have to be modified to `try`...`catch` for your mysql error. (don't know how to do this).

Said I could also do this procedurally (in PHP) by making a series of queries that do this:

```
LOCK TABLES jobs WRITE;

SELECT count(*) as countof FROM jobs
WHERE job_number = $job_number
AND (($number_from BETWEEN number_from AND number_to) OR ($number_to BETWEEN number_from AND number_to));

// Fetch the result, and if it's == 0, then you insert.

UNLOCK TABLES
```

To avoid the overlapping you can do it via triggers or by writing application logic (in PHP in your case). In both cases you would need as parameters `new_number_from` and `new_number_to`. The former is the number_from value of the new entry. The latter is the `number_to` value of the new entry. You would also need `new_job_number`.

The query below returns all rows that overlap with the range specified by the parameters `$new_number_from` and `$new_number_to` for job with id `$job_number`

```
SELECT * 
FROM jobs
WHERE job_number=$jobNumber 
AND number_from <= $new_number_to
AND number_to >= $new_number_from
```

If you implement this using PHP, you could execute this query and check if any row is returned. If an empty resultset is returned then there is no conflict. Otherwise there is a conflict.

NOTE: You may prefer to get the count (`SELECT COUNT(*)`) instead of returning lines (`SELECT *`)

Comment: NOTE THAT JOB_NUMBER IS unique to a job

Comment: i just dont know how to write a good trigger statement or procedure. call daft but am entirely new to trigger and procedures

Comment: Stackoverflow is not for people to « write code for you ». Show us what you have already done, and the errors you got. Then we will help you to correct your code and go into the right directions.

Comment: sure i know. i have written some codes myself just a bit frustrated thats all